# TensorFlow - tf.layers vs tf.contrib.layers

Tags: python, tensorflow

In TensorFlow, [`tf.layers`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers) and [`tf.contrib.layers`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.layers) share a lot of functionality (standard 2D convolutional layers, batch normalization layers, etc). Is the difference between these two just that the `contrib.layers` package is still experimental where the `layers` package is considered stable? Or is one being replaced by the other? Other differences? Why are these two separate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've answered your own question. The description on the official documentation for the [`tf.contrib`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib) namespace is:

> contrib module containing volatile or experimental code.

So `tf.contrib` is reserved for experimental features. APIs in this namespace are allowed to change rapidly between versions, whereas the others usually can't without a new major version. In particular, the functions in `tf.contrib.layers` are not identical to those found in `tf.layers`, although some of them might be replicated with different names.

As for whether you should use them, that depends on whether you are willing to handle sudden breaking changes. Code that doesn't rely on `tf.contrib` may be easier to migrate to future versions of TensorFlow.

Comment: Is there any reason that much of the functionality is duplicated between these modules? Are the versions in tf.contrib.layers, say, experimental versions with better optimization or something? Or are they just leftover from before the layers module was added to tf for historical reasons?

Comment: @erobert That may have to be evaluated on a case-by-case basis. Often, `tf.contrib` enables the community to experiment with different APIs and expose less stable features in the process. As such, they do not have to disappear immediately after a new feature lands. Likewise, they may also be completely changed or cleaned up on a minor release. At the moment, for example, `tf.layers.conv2d` and `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d` have different prototypes and are not always interchangeable.