# Replace "from tensorflow.contrib import layers"

Tags: tensorflow

How to replace `from tensorflow.contrib import layers` with new core functionality. I want to move my TF 1.4 code to 1.12 in preparation for TF 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, can you upgrade this comment to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core functionality corresponding to [`tf.contrib.layers`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers) is in [`tf.layers`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers). Some of the differences are discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805675/tensorflow-tf-layers-vs-tf-contrib-layers). However this will not prepare you for TF 2.0.

If your goal is to prepare your code for TF 2.0, consider that `tf.contrib` will be removed entirely (either split from TF or integrated into it) and that `tf.layers` too will be removed and the high-level API will reside under [`tf.keras`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras). So to best prepare for TF 2.0 you should start using `tf.keras.layers` instead.

Here is a [blog post](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/gan/2018/11/04/tensorflow-2-models-migration-and-new-design/) about some of the practical differences to expect with TF 2.0.

Comment: So basically, replace tf.contrib.layers with tf.keras.layers